# How to prevent anonymous users reading couchdb?

Tags: couchdb, anonymous

I want to remotely manage couchdb by curl using the administrator account, but I found that anonymous users can also read some information , like _all_dbs, which is not what I want. It seems that couchdb allows anonymous users using GET and HEAD methods, so how can I prevent it? What I want is only administrators are allowed.

I have made the following settings in local.ini:

```
require_valid_user = true
WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="administrator"
```

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you disabled [Admin party](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/config/auth.html#server-administrators) mode. Try setting both valid users fields like so:

```
[couch_httpd_auth]
require_valid_user = true

[chttpd]
require_valid_user = true
```

As per the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/config/auth.html#authentication-configuration), one is for clustered port and the other is node-local port.

EDIT: I forgot about the membership.

You need to set each Database [Security object](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/security.html). And put some members in the `members` and `admins` fields. You can do this via Fauxton GUI by clicking on the "lock" icon next to each database. Or by doing `PUT /db/_security` with the appropriate [json](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/security.html). From the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/security.html) (emphasis mine).

> If there are any member names or roles defined for a database, then **only** authenticated users having a matching name or role are allowed to **read** documents from the database.

Comment: Yes, I have made these config, and anonymous users cannot update documents anymore, but they can still read all the documents, but in fact, what i want is anonymous users shouldn't be able to read any info.

Comment: Ok. I think you also need to add "database members" through permissions. It can be done easily in Fauxton UI or via `PUT /db/_security` See http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/security.html

Comment: Updated my answer with this info.